# Can't find pomodoro app installed using appcenter

Tags: release-loki, appcenter

I installed this [Pomodoro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XhlX.png) application from AppCenter. But I can't find the app in Slingshot(app menu) on searching.

How do I open this app?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, my solution was to simply grabbed the deb file from the author's official website and install it whit Eddy.

Comment: this looks like a gnome-shell app that's in the appcenter by mistake, because those apps aren't natively supported by gala/elementaryOS yet.

Answer (score 1):

You always can try it manually, just follow the docs! [HERE](https://github.com/tomatoers/tomato)